# Adding custom structure to GSList with Glib

Tags: c, linked-list, structure, glib, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to add a structure to a singly linked list with the function g_slist_append(list, &structure). This seems to work (it's adding the pointer), however I can't seem to find a way to view the elements in the structure when reading the linked list.

My structure looks like this:

```
 struct customstruct
 {
   int var1;
   int var2;
   char *string_1;
 }
```

Then, I make a list: `GSList *list = NULL;`

Then, I append one instance of the structure like this:

```
 struct customstruct list_entry;
 list_entry.var1 = 1;
 list_entry.var2 = 2;
 list_entry.string_1 = "String";

 list = g_slist_append(list, &entry);

 printf("Entry var1 = %d\n", list->data->var1);
```

That last line fails because `var1` can't be found (request for member in something not a struct or union).

I think I need to cast it to the right type but I don't know how. Anyone?

Comment: Be careful with code like that, if `list_entry` goes out of scope the list will still hold it's old address, which you cannot dereference at that point.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the possible segfault!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing the `data` member of the `GSList` structure is a `void` pointer, i.e. a pointer that can point to anything but doesn't have any other type info.

This means you have to use type-casting:

```
((struct customstruct *) list->data)->var1
```

Comment: I was experimenting with that, however, I didn't come up with the idea of only type-casting `list->data`. I tried it this way: `(struct customstruct *)list->data->var1`. Anyway, thanks for the answer!