# GSList of structs

Tags: c, struct, glib

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561108/adding-custom-structure-to-gslist-with-glib) thread, which helped me figure out dereferencing properly, but then I went and created exactly the situation that post's answer's author said to avoid, haha.

What I'm trying to accomplish is the creation of a basic file browser (per the [book](http://www.gtkbook.com/) I'm reading). The code below is supposed to be reading through the directory contents and filling the details I've chosen into a `struct`. That `struct` is then appended as the `data` member of a `GSList`. That list is then used to populate row data for a `GtkTreeView`, and so forth.

```
typedef struct
{
    gchar *name, *size, *date_modified;
}FileProperties;

//...

static void refresh_directory_listing(GtkTreeView *treeview)
{
    GtkListStore *store = gtk_list_store_new(NUM_COLUMNS, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING);
    GSList *files = NULL;
    GtkTreeIter iter;

    get_current_directory_contents(&files);

    for(GSList *current = files; current != NULL; current = g_slist_next(current))
    {
        gtk_list_store_append(store, &iter);
        gtk_list_store_set(store, &iter, FILE_NAME, ((FileProperties *) current->data)->name,
                                         FILE_SIZE, ((FileProperties *) current->data)->size,
                                         DATE_MODIFIED, ((FileProperties *) current->data)->date_modified, -1);
    }

    gtk_tree_view_set_model(treeview, GTK_TREE_MODEL(store));
    g_object_unref(store);
    g_slist_free(files);
}

static void get_current_directory_contents(GSList **files)
{
    GDir *current_dir = g_dir_open(g_get_current_dir(), 0, NULL);
    gchar *file_name = NULL;
    FileProperties *file = g_malloc(sizeof(FileProperties));

    while((file_name = (gchar *) g_dir_read_name(current_dir)))
    {
        memset(file, 0, sizeof(FileProperties));

        file->name = g_strdup(file_name);
        file->size = g_strdup_printf("Nope");
        file->date_modified = g_strdup_printf("Nuh uh");

        *files = g_slist_append(*files, file);
    }

    g_free(file);
}
```

Working to understand why my file names return blank and everybody has the same memory address, it's obvious to me that `g_slist_append()` is handing the `FileProperties` structure over directly. So, everything references the same `struct` that keeps getting overwritten and eventually freed. Whoops.

My question is this: what would be the appropriate way to hand a `GSList` of `struct`'s back and forth between functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only allocating *one* `FileProperties` structure before the `while` loop, and then you just change the contents of that single struct, and append it many times.

You need to allocate *one* `FileProperties` structure instance for each file whose properties you want to store.

Move the allocation inside the loop, replacing the (spurious) `memset()`:

```
while((file_name = (gchar *) g_dir_read_name(current_dir)))
{
    FileProperties *file = g_malloc(sizeof *file);

    /* rest of loop here ... */
}
```

Comment: Cool. Thank you. Simple misunderstanding of memory business. =)